# RedisJSON - MGET Example?

Tags: redis, redisjson, redislabs

I am using RedisJSON and I can't figure out how to get the full JSON values stored for multiple keys, following the documentation on the [official site of the plugin](https://oss.redislabs.com/redisjson/commands/).

For example, from the `redis-cli`:

```
redis-cli-1234> json.set k1 . '{"a":"a" }'
OK
redis-cli-1234> json.set k2 . '{"b":"b" }'
OK
```

Now I would like to run a command that would get k1, k2 (the keys of the desired values) and return their values, in one-go:

```
1) "{\"a\":\"a\"}"
2) "{\"b\":\"b\"}"
```

But I can't figure out how.

I've tried:

```
redis-cli-1234> json.mget k1 k2 .
```

And several other stuff, but I can only get redis to return either one value or the other, bot not both.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

https://redis.io/topics/transactions

```
redis-cloud:6379> multi
OK
redis-cloud:6379(TX)> json.get k1
QUEUED
redis-cloud:6379(TX)> json.get k2
QUEUED
redis-cloud:6379(TX)> exec
1) "{\"a\":\"a\"}"
2) "{\"b\":\"b\"}"
```

Comment: Thanks. This doesn't work for me for some reason, getting this error:
redis-cloud-85> multi
OK
redis-cloud-85> json.get k1
QUEUED
redis-cloud-85> json.get k2
(error) CROSSSLOT Keys in request don't hash to the same slot (context='within MULTI', command='json.get', original-slot='12706', wrong-slot='449', first-key='k1', violating-key='k2')

Comment: @orcaman it seems like you're running with a Redis Cluster. Redis Transaction can't have cross slots operations. You can keys hash tags, see: https://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec#keys-hash-tags

Comment: @GuyKorland thanks! Yup, running on Redis Labs :-). Is mget not really working for the RedisJSON plugin? Or at least not working as I have expected? I switched to working with standard SET and MGET for now (instead of the JSON.SET and JSON.MGET plugin functionality).